# Use single sparkContext to iterate on a function mutliple times

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have `pyspark` script that is working fine. This script will fetch data from mysql and create hive tables.

The `pyspark` script is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

#Condition to specify exact number of arguments in the spark-submit command line
if len(sys.argv) != 8:
    print "Invalid number of args......"
    print "Usage: spark-submit import.py Arguments"
    exit()
table = sys.argv[1]
hivedb = sys.argv[2]
domain = sys.argv[3]
port=sys.argv[4]
mysqldb=sys.argv[5]
username=sys.argv[6]
password=sys.argv[7]

df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "{}:{}/{}".format(domain,port,mysqldb)).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","{}".format(table)).option("user", "{}".format(username)).option("password", "{}".format(password)).load()

#Register dataframe as table
df.registerTempTable("mytempTable")

# create hive table from temp table:
sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))

sc.stop()
```

Now this `pyspark` script will be invoked by using a `shell` script. For this shell script I am passing table names as arguments from a file.

The `shell script` is below.

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/$USER/spark/source.sh
[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0 table ";exit 1; }

args_file=$1

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

#Function to get the status of the job creation
function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                #echo "Please find the attached log file for more details"
                exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
}

# For sql_spark.py
spark-submit --name "${table}" --master "yarn-client" --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 6g  --executor-cores 1 --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=609" /home/$USER/spark/sql_spark.py ${table} ${hivedb} ${domain} ${port} ${mysqldb} ${username} ${password} > /tmp/logging/${table}.log 2>&1

g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS "Spark job ${table} Execution"

echo "************************************************************************************************************************************************************************"
```

Now I have more than 200 tables in mysql. So effectvely I have to use spark-submit 200 times to fetch the tables from mysql to hive.

Each time I use spark-submit it takes 10 -12 seconds for sparkcontext to be created. So effectievely 33 minutes of time is being used to create sparkcontext.

I want to reduce this time by using only one sparkcontext.

Now what I want to do is I want to use only one spark Context and import all the 200 tables from mysql to hive.

I have created a `function` using `total code` in the script. I have tried like below. I am able to use a single `sparkContext` and achieve my requirement but not sure if it is the correct method.

`New spark script`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

#Condition to specify exact number of arguments in the spark-submit command line
if len(sys.argv) != 8:
    print "Invalid number of args......"
    print "Usage: spark-submit import.py Arguments"
    exit()
args_file = sys.argv[1]
hivedb = sys.argv[2]
domain = sys.argv[3]
port=sys.argv[4]
mysqldb=sys.argv[5]
username=sys.argv[6]
password=sys.argv[7]

def testing(table, hivedb, domain, port, mysqldb, username, password):

    print "*********************************************************table = {} ***************************".format(table)
    df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "{}:{}/{}".format(domain,port,mysqldb)).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","{}".format(table)).option("user", "{}".format(username)).option("password", "{}".format(password)).load()

    #Register dataframe as table
    df.registerTempTable("mytempTable")

    # create hive table from temp table:
    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} stored as parquet as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))

input = sc.textFile('/user/XXXXXXX/spark_args/%s' %args_file).collect()

for table in input:
 testing(table, hivedb, domain, port, mysqldb, username, password)

sc.stop()
```

Could anyone suggest if there is any alternative or whether what I am doing is completely wrong.